# Position a notification next to calling select element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery notification plugin from: http://www.richardhsu.me/jquery.ambiance/

The way I call the plugin is from a select element using the chosen plugin. What I would like to do is position the message box next to the select element that fired the message. In this case, id="box_frtv". Is it possible to amend the code to achieve this. Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Thought this might work, but it doesn't. Being overridden by the css.

```
$(function() { 
$("#box_frtv").chosen({

 width: "250px",
 max_selected_options: 1

 });
 $("#box_frtv").bind("chosen:maxselected",
            function() {

            $("#boxError").ambiance({message: "Uh oh the fading is gone!",
            type: "error",
            fade: true}); 
        });
      });
```

html code

```
<div class="fieldset">
            <h1><span>Select Your Box(es)</span></h1>
            <p>
              <select data-placeholder="Choose your box(es)..." class="chosen-select" name="box_frtv[]" id="box_frtv" multiple required="required">
                <option value=""></option>

              </select><span></span><div id="boxError"></div>
            </p>
          </div>
```

css code

```
/*
 * Stylesheet for Ambiance - Notification Plugin for jQuery
 * Version 1.0.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Richard Hsu
 * Documentation: http://www.github.com/richardhsu/jquery.ambiance
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 */

/* Notification area will be top right but feel free to modify it below. */
#ambiance-notification {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

/* Built in custom styling for the notifications. */
.ambiance-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ambiance {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.ambiance:hover {
  border: 3px solid #DDDDDD;
}

.ambiance-default, .ambiance-success, .ambiance-error {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier. */
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.ambiance-default {
  background: #000000;
  color: #DDDDDD;
}

.ambiance-success {
  background: #468847;
  color: #DFF0D8;
}

.ambiance-error {
  background: #B94A48;
  color: #F2DEDE;
}

/* Close button attributes -- based off Twitter Bootstrap alert close item. */
.ambiance-close {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ambiance-close:hover {
  color: #BBBBBB;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: By "next to", do you mean "to the right of"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but it's appearance is going to be determined by the size and location of the `select` element.

```
#boxError {
    display: inline;
    color: #F00;
    position: relative;
    top: -69px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to replace any of the original css?

Comment: In that case, it isn't changing the position of the message. Could it be because the position is fixed at 10px 10px? Thanks

Comment: It's `#ambiance-notification` that you're trying to relocate? Not `#boxError`?

Comment: The original css is as posted. There is no #ambiance-notification in my markup. I am assuming that the #ambiance-notification is within the jquery file itself. However, i created a div with id="#ambiance-notification", but still it positions the message away from the div.

Comment: Right-click the message in the browser when it comes up and let's see if we can determine what element it is.

Comment: This is what is appearing in firebug: <div id="ambiance-notification"><div class="ambiance ambiance-error" style="width: 300px;"><a class="ambiance-close" href="#_">×</a>Uh oh the fading is gone!</div></div> Funny thing is that is placing this div beneath my footer.

Comment: Ok, try replacing the CSS for `#ambiance-notification` with what I've given you for `#boxError`.